# propagate carry bit between two ASM GCC inline block

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, clang++

Dear Assembly/C++ dev,

> The question is: Does propagate the carry (or any flag) between two ASM block is realistic or totally insane, even if it works ?

A few years ago I developed an integer library for large arithmetic lower than 512 bits (at compile time). I did not use GMP at this time because for this scale, GMP become slower due to the memory allocation and the model choose for the binary representation [bench](http://comp-phys.org/vli/bench.html).

I must confess I created my ASM ( the string block) using `BOOST_PP`, it is not very glorious (for curious have a look on it [vli](https://github.com/timocafe/vli)). The library was working well.

However I remark at this time it was impossible to propagate the carry flag of the state register between two ASM inline block. This is logical because for any mnemonic generated by the compiler between two blocks, the register is reset ( except for the `mov` instruction (from my assembly knowledge)).

Yesterday I get an idea to propagate the carry between two ASM block a bit tricky (using a recursive algo). It is working but I think I am lucky.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

//forward declaration
template<std::size_t NumBits>
struct integer;


//helper using object function, partial specialization  is forbiden on functions
template <std::size_t NumBits, std::size_t W, bool K = W == integer<NumBits>::numwords>
struct helper {
    static inline void add(integer<NumBits> &a, const integer<NumBits> &b){
        helper<NumBits, integer<NumBits>::numwords>::add(a,b);
    }
};

// first addition (call first)
template<std::size_t NumBits, std::size_t W>
struct helper<NumBits, W, 1> {
    static inline void add(integer<NumBits> &a, const integer<NumBits> &b){
        __asm__ (
                              "movq %1, %%rax \n"
                              "addq %%rax, %0 \n"
                              : "+m"(a[0]) // output
                              : "m" (b[0]) // input only
                              : "rax", "cc", "memory");
        helper<NumBits,W-1>::add(a,b);
    }
};

//second and more propagate the carry (call next)
template<std::size_t NumBits, std::size_t W>
struct helper<NumBits, W, 0> {
    static inline void add(integer<NumBits> &a, const integer<NumBits> &b){
        __asm__ (
                              "movq %1, %%rax \n"
                              "adcq %%rax, %0 \n"
                              : "+m"(a[integer<NumBits>::numwords-W])
                              : "m" (b[integer<NumBits>::numwords-W])
                              : "rax", "cc", "memory");
        helper<NumBits,W-1>::add(a,b);
    }
};

//nothing end reccursive process (call last)
template<std::size_t NumBits>
struct helper<NumBits, 0, 0> {
    static inline void add(integer<NumBits> &a, const integer<NumBits> &b){};
};

// tiny integer class
template<std::size_t NumBits>
struct integer{
    typedef uint64_t      value_type;
    static const std::size_t numbits = NumBits;
    static const std::size_t numwords = (NumBits+std::numeric_limits<value_type>::digits-1)/std::numeric_limits<value_type>::digits;
    using container = std::array<uint64_t, numwords>;

    typedef typename container::iterator             iterator;

    iterator begin() { return data_.begin();}
    iterator end() { return data_.end();}

    explicit integer(value_type num = value_type()){
        assert( -1l >> 1 == -1l );
        std::fill(begin(),end(),value_type());
        data_[0] = num;
    }

    inline value_type& operator[](std::size_t n){ return data_[n];}
    inline const value_type& operator[](std::size_t n) const { return data_[n];}

    integer& operator+=(const integer& a){
        helper<numbits,numwords>::add(*this,a);
        return *this;
    }

    integer& operator~(){
        std::transform(begin(),end(),begin(),std::bit_not<value_type>());
        return *this;
    }

    void print_raw(std::ostream& os) const{
        os << "(" ;
        for(std::size_t i = numwords-1; i > 0; --i)
            os << data_[i]<<" ";
        os << data_[0];
        os << ")";
    }

    void print(std::ostream& os) const{
        assert(false && " TO DO ! \n");
    }

private:
    container data_;
};

template <std::size_t NumBits>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, integer<NumBits> const& i){
    if(os.flags() & std::ios_base::hex)
        i.print_raw(os);
    else
        i.print(os);
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    integer<256> a; // 0
    integer<256> b(1);

    ~a; //all the 0 become 1

    std::cout << " a: " << std::hex << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ref: (ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff) " <<  std::endl;

    a += b; // should propagate the carry

    std::cout << " a+=b: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ref: (0 0 0 0) " <<  std::endl; // it works but ...

    return 0;
}
```

I get a correct result (it must be compiled in release -O2 or -O3!) and the ASM is right (on my Mac with clang++: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2))

```
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, -64(%rbp)

    ## InlineAsm End
    ## InlineAsm Start
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rax
    adcq    %rax, -56(%rbp)

    ## InlineAsm End
    ## InlineAsm Start
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rax
    adcq    %rax, -48(%rbp)

    ## InlineAsm End
    ## InlineAsm Start
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rax
    adcq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
```

I am conscient it is working because during the optimization the compiler remove all useless instruction between the ASM block (in debug mode it failed).

What do you think ? Definitively unsafe ? Does a compiler guy know how much it will be stable ?

To conclude: I am just doing that for fun :) Yes, GMP is the solution for large arithmetic !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `__volatile__` is an abuse.

The purpose of `__volatile__` is to force the compiler to emit the assembly code at the written location, rather than relying on data flow analysis to figure this out. If you are doing ordinary manipulations of data in user space, usually you should not be using `__volatile__`, and if you need `__volatile__` to get your code to work it almost always means that your operands are specified incorrectly.

And yes, the operands are specified incorrectly. Let's look at the first block.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
                      "movq %1, %%rax \n"
                      "addq %%rax, %0 \n"
                      : "=m"(a[0]) // output
                      : "m" (b[0]) // input only
                      : "rax", "memory");
```

There are two errors here.

- The constraint on the output `"=m"(a[0])` is incorrect. Recall that the destination for `addq` is both an input and an output, so the correct constraint is +, so use `"+m"(a[0])`. If you tell the compiler that `a[0]` is output only, the compiler may arrange `a[0]` to contain a garbage value (through dead store elimination), which is not what you want.
- The flags are missing from the assembly specification. Without telling the compiler that the flags are modified, the compiler may assume that the flags are preserved across the assembly block, which will cause the compiler to generate incorrect code elsewhere.

Unfortunately, the flags are only available as output or clobber operands to assembly blocks, and are not available as inputs. So after all that fuss over specifying operands correctly so you don't use `__volatile__`... it turns out that there isn't a good way to specify your operands anyway!

So the recommendation here is that you should *at least* fix the operands you can fix, and specify `"cc"` as a clobber. But there are a couple better solutions that do not require `__volatile__` at all...

### Solution #1: Use GMP.

The `mpn_` functions for addition do not allocate memory. The `mpz_` functions are wrappers around the `mpn_` functions with some extra logic and memory allocations.

### Solution #2: Write everything in one assembly block.

If you write the entire loop in one assembly block, you don't have to worry about preserving flags between blocks. You can use assembly macros to do this. Excuse the mess, I'm not much of an assembly programmer:

```
template <int N>
void add(unsigned long long *dest, unsigned long long *src) {
  __asm__(
      "movq (%1), %%rax"
      "\n\taddq %%rax, (%0)"
      "\n.local add_offset"
      "\n.set add_offset,0"
      "\n.rept %P2" // %P0 means %0 but without the $ in front
      "\n.set add_offset,add_offset+8"
      "\n\tmovq add_offset(%1), %%rax"
      "\n\tadcq %%rax, add_offset(%0)"
      "\n.endr"
      :
      : "r"(dest), "r"(src), "n"(N-1)
      : "cc", "memory", "rax");
}
```

What this does is evaluate the loop using the `.rept` assembly directive. You will ultimately get 1 copy of `addq` and N-1 copies of `adcq`, although if you look at the assembly output of GCC with `-S` you will only see one of each. The assembler itself will create the copies, unwinding the loop.

See Gist: https://gist.github.com/depp/966fc1f4d535e31d9725cc71d97daf91

Comment: thank you very much for your answer:
- about GMP I did a mistake, I understood GMP does not use the 2complementary method, but unsigned integer and one bit for the sign. It facilitates the multiplication but slow down addition.
- Your ASM is very nice and I learn new think, but it was not really the question. Does propagate the carry (or whatever flag in the state register) between two ASM block make sense or it is just insane :)

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that the `mpn_` functions do allocate memory for multiplication for larger inputs. There are no known sub-quadratic multiplication algorithms that don't require auxiliary memory. But this is somewhat besides the point since the OP is asking about addition.

Comment: @Mysticial: Clarified.

Comment: @Timocafé: The answer for your question is in the text. You can't specify flags as inputs to inline assembler, so you can't pass the flags between blocks unless you put the flags somewhere else, like a general purpose register, which is undesirable.

Comment: @Timocafé: While `mpz_` functions use unsigned integers + one bit for sign, that does not mean that the underlying `mpn_` work that way. Take a look at `mpn_add`, for example. It's just regular unsigned number addition, which you can use as a base for either sign-magnitude or twos-complement. The `mpz_add` function will either call `mpn_sub` or `mpn_add` depending on whether the arguments have the same or different sign.

Comment: @Timocafé: It is common for inline assembly to work "by accident".

Comment: Just side note. On x86 and x86-64 the `"cc"` clobber is effectively meaningless. GCC assumes the flags are always clobbered by inline assembly. This isn't the case for other target platforms.For consistency and self documentation it isn't a bad idea to use it but it isn't required.

Comment: I'd probably do it this way: `unsigned long long tempr;
  __asm__(
      "movq (%[src]), %[tempr]"
      "\n\taddq %[tempr], (%[dest])"
      "\n.local add_offset"
      "\n.set add_offset,0"
      "\n.rept %P[N]" // %P0 means %0 but without the $ in front
      "\n.set add_offset,add_offset+8"
      "\n\tmovq add_offset(%[src]), %[tempr]"
      "\n\tadcq %[tempr], add_offset(%[dest])"
      "\n.endr"
      : "=m" (*(unsigned long long (*)[N]) dest), [tempr]"=&r"(tempr)
      : [dest]"r"(dest), [src]"r"(src), [N]"n"(N-1), "m"(*(const unsigned long long (*)[N]) src)
      : "cc");`

Comment: Rather than use memory clobber we tell the compiler dest is an array of N elements that will be modified. src is an array of N elements and it will be read from.We use a dummy variable to allow the compiler to choose the temporary register (has to be early clobber since it is modified before all the input constraints have been read. The memory operands are not actually used by the template but they tell the compiler whether the arrays are modified or not. This allows you to pass the pointers through registers but also tell the compiler the complete side effects of the template.